# YouTube API: How to get videos from channel X with tag Y?

Tags: json, youtube-api

For example, how could I get a JSON response of all the videos from channel "http://www.youtube.com/nba" that are tagged "playoffs"?

Comment: if all else fails you can scrape this: http://www.youtube.com/results?search=tag&suggested_categories=17&search_query=%40nba

Comment: I think you should mark the most voted answer as correct...

Comment: @Lipis it is my own answer. :)

Comment: Working solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30125715/975169, by the way for gettting channelId look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14366648/how-can-i-get-a-channel-id-from-youtube

Answer (score 15, accepted):

YouTube calls `tags` as `categories`.

The following URL shows videos from `NBA` channel with tags `playoffs` and `sports` (you can add more obviously) in JSON.

http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/nba/uploads/-/sports/playoffs?v=2&alt=json

Comment: I tried this, but most of my tagged videos does not appear in the result. I have found [this track](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=4247#makechanges) in Youtube Issues and I think that bug persists.

Answer (score 4):

Try something like this:

http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/nba/uploads?q=playoffs

but this is xml format, look the api document and do it as json by yourself.

Comment: Thanks yuli chika! This is very close to what I am looking for and may work. But, my goal is to search by tag and not by "q" (http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/reference.html#qsp) as your example shows. Any idea how to search by tag?

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for the `category`-parameter. <s>I ran a quick test to see how well it matches. Here's the result (yes, the page will load for a few seconds).</s>

- <s>This link will show you the results and how well they match 'playoffs' with the keywords, when using category.</s>
- <s>This link will show you the results when using the q-parameter.</s>

So, I guess the link you're looking for is:

http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/nba/uploads?category=playoffs&alt=json