# YouTube: Searching my channel for tags x AND y

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, gdata

I wish to search my channel for any video that has tagX **AND** tagY. As per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5988604/526495), I've tried the following URL:

http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/myusername/uploads/-/tagX/tagY?v=2

But this is just doing a very fuzzy **OR** search on the tags. How can I get my desired result?