# Youtube API v3 Search own videos by tag

Tags: google-api, youtube-api, google-api-client

Is it possible to search videos by tags using Youtube API v3 ?
I would like to search among my own videos.

Answer (score 6):

Use [`search`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list) method with `##tagname` search string for `q` parameter and set `type:video` parameter. You can find other search operators [here](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/2685977?hl=en). Old one - `tag:tangle` doesn't work with new api for me. `##` works fine.

Comment: How did you get this to work? Did you authorize the request as a content partner?

Comment: @kjosh use your API key:    `GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&q=%23%23{YOUR_TAG}&key={YOUR_API_KEY}`

Comment: Doesn't seem to work anymore? Are there any other ways?

Answer (score 1):

Recently tried the solution given by user [350D](https://stackoverflow.com/users/819764/350d), but `q=##{YOUR_TAG}` does not appear to work with the latest YouTube API. It appears that the tag can only be retrieved when the video ID is provided as a parameter. I found that the following works for me:

First, retrieve a list of videos (returning minimal needed information, e.g. the video ID, title, and the high quality thumbnail URL):

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key={YOUR API KEY}&fields=items(id(videoId),snippet(title,thumbnails(high(url))))&part=id,snippet;
```

Then batch the video IDs into one request to retrieve the associated tags:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?key={YOUR API KEY}&fields=items(id,snippet(tags))&part=snippet&id={videoID01,videoID02,etc};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do a [videos->list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list) with with settings video ids as the ones in your [playlist](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list) and iterate through them checking with tags. But searching by tags is not available in API anymore.