# Is it possible to list YouTube videos based purely on a tag value?

Tags: youtube-api

I am looking at the [YouTube v3 API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list),

Where there is a `q` parameter for the query

[image]

But I am unsure if it's even possible to list videos based on tag values, or is it always a free text similar search?

Comment: [Unfortunately](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16674813), it seems like searching by tags is no longer possible. Could you just search for keywords instead?

Comment: Do you mind writing this as an answer? In that case I can mark it as the right answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Unfortunately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16672685/youtube-api-v3-search-own-videos-by-tag/16674813#16674813), it seems like searching by tags is no longer possible. In fact, it would be a bit cumbersome to search by tags because they are no longer visible on YouTube videos; you'd have to go to the page's source and search for `keyword`. You could just search for keywords instead, depending on how accurate you'd like your results to be.

Answer (score 0):

You need to retrieve the video IDs first, and then use those video IDs to retrieve the associated tags.

For example, to retrieve a list of videos (returning only the needed information e.g. the video ID, title and the high quality thumbnail URL, etc.) use:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key={YOUR API KEY}&fields=items(id(videoId),snippet(title,thumbnails(high(url))))&part=id,snippet;
```

And then batch the video IDs into one request to retrieve the associated tags:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?key={YOUR API KEY}&fields=items(id,snippet(tags))&part=snippet&id={videoID01,videoID02,etc};
```

See also [Youtube API v3 Search own videos by tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16672685/youtube-api-v3-search-own-videos-by-tag/36047872#36047872)