# Retrieve youtube video list based on custom tags/keywords/catogories/sections/groups

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-api

I am trying to group my videos based on custom tags/keywords and make a dropdown of those tags/keywords. So when one of those tags/keywords is selected, the playlist refreshes loading only those videos related to that tag/keyword.

This is possible to achieve in v2 but in v3,unless we mention the video-id we cannot retrieve the list of tags/keywords.

Is there a way to organise and retrieve youtube videos to achieve above functionality.

Comment: Here is the link for v2  https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_uploading_videos#Assigning_Developer_Tags

Comment: Welcome to SO! What have you tried so far? To help us help you, please add a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I actually tried to group my videos based on tags, but realised that we cannot get the tag list of all videos at once, moreover we should be the owner of the videos to get tag-list. 
So googled more and came to know that developer keywords and tags were used only in v2,not anymore. 
Can we use q parameter as keyword search tool.

Comment: Apparently you can only search videos by [keywords](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list). As stated in the related SO [post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36047872/5995040), you can not search videos using tag and it is not working with YouTube API v3. It appears that the tag can only be retrieved when the video ID is provided as a parameter. Hope this helps.